# creating a directory tree structure using bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a directory tree structure that has a parent , children and leaf nodes where each leaf nodes has a dependency on each other , like wise with the children nodes and parent.

Firstly , Has anyone succeeded doing this using bash scripting before?  Need to add the directory name and then later traverse through the tree.

Comment: have no idea what you want. Can you provide some example?

Comment: What do you mean by a dependency?

Comment: in a proper directory structure, how can your "leaf nodes" have dependecy on each other?

Comment: mkdir -p creates all the parent directories needed to a file. e.g. mkdir -p a/b/c/d/e/f.txt but I really don't understand the question

Comment: unclear question, unclear objective.

Answer (score 0):

It's not real clear what you're thinking, but you *can* always call a BASH function recursively.  Here's an example factorial:

```
VALUE=1
function fact {
    if [ $1 -le 0 ]
    then
       echo $VALUE
    else
       let VALUE=VALUE*$1
       fact $(($1-1))
    fi
}
fact $1

$ bash fact.bash 5
120
```

So you can write recursive functions to build and traverse your tree just as you would in another language.

One question, though: why do you want to do this in a shell script?  Why not, say, python?